# nginx Rewrite Rules to Re-write Every Match Of a Certain Regex Except

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, uri

I'm writing rewrite rules in nginx.

**I want to rewrite every URI that matches `/A/B[anything]` to `/X/` *except* `/A/B/C[/]`.**

**How do I do this?**

> 

What I've tried:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/A/B/C/?) {
    break;
}
rewrite ^/A/B   /X/   permanent;
```

This rewrites `/A/B` to `/X/`, but `/A/B[anything]` doesn't get redirected, nor does `/A/B/C/` stay at `/A/B/C/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

I needed to make the rewrite line

```
rewrite ^/A/B(.*)?   /X/   permanent;
```

The `(.*)?` means " and optionally match anything any amount of times."

Answer (score 0):

```
rewrite ^/A/B/?$   /X/   permanent;
```

Should do it

Comment: Close, but that doesn't work because I want /A/B[anything] to get redirected to /X/. I've updated the question to make it clearer.