# How to rewrite domain in nginx ingress?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to configure ingress rewrite rule for my domain as follows
https://example.com/?page=emailVerify&token=fhgfgfkhfkfkhfhjfhfhj&lang=en_US

to:
https://example.com/my_api/?page=emailVerify&token=fhgfgfkhfkfkhfhjfhfhj&lang=en_US

I tried with annotation but it replacing the etire query string

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /my_api/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use permanent rewrites. Take a look: [nginx-rewrite-rules-to-re-write-every-match-of-a-certain-regex-except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917403/nginx-rewrite-rules-to-re-write-every-match-of-a-certain-regex-except).

You can also use annotation [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) . Add following line to your ingress definition: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: my_path/$1`

Useful article: [nginx-rewrite-examples](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/08/nginx-rewrite-examples/).